# PHP not sending emails, no errors in logs

Tags: php, sendmail, ubuntu-9.04

I've got an Ubuntu server set up with PHP 5.2, apache and sendmail.  I've got some Drupal sites that should be sending emails but are not.  I don't see any errors in the apache logs and there appears to be nothing in /var/log/mail.log.  What do I need to do to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the config section related to sendmail is commented out in the php.ini file.

Look for:

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
```

In your php.ini file. Note that there could be more than one php.ini file, for example for the CLI php, and one for the Apache module.